# Xcode6 localization duplicate

Tags: objective-c, localization, ios8, xcode6

After migrating project to XCode6 I got next strange thing: 
[image: two english localizations].

When I trying to remove one of them both removed. How can I fix this?

Also, I have problem with uploading binary to AppStore - it passes validation during upload, but I get 'invalid binary' status after about 20-30 minutes. I suppose subj of my question could be the reason of this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on your project.
2. Select "Show the version editor" (top right side of the screen). Your project should be shown as sourcecode.
3. Find in your project source (`cmd+f`)  "**Begin PBXProject section**".
4. Below you should see key-values pair: `knownRegions`. Here you should have en, two times. Just remove one of them.

For example my project looks like that:

```
buildConfigurationList = E37ABA1218083A4100EC41AC /* Build configuration list for PBXProject "MyProjectName" */;
            compatibilityVersion = "Xcode 3.2";
            developmentRegion = English;
            hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
            knownRegions = (
                en,
                Base,
                pl,
            );
```

Comment: Correct. Thanks, but (for academical purposes) there was not two "en", but "en" and "English". Interesting, what the difference...